# How to convert a data frame into binary numbers (1's and 0's)?

Tags: r

So I have some gene expression count data with the columns containing all my samples and each row containing ~60000 genes. I've transformed the data to TPM and I would like to exclude certain genes below a TPM threshold of 5. To do this I need to covert TPM values > 5 into 1's using `df[df > 5] <- 1` but also convert TPM values < 5 into 0's as shown below. What code can do this?

```
Gene       Sample A  Sample B          Gene       Sample A  Sample B
Gene 1      10.23     11.20            Gene 1        1        1
Gene 2       2.89      6.76            Gene 2        0        1
Gene 3       9.66      4.34            Gene 3        1        0
...                                    ...
```

Comment: can you share the example of input table? But based on your description, I think a simple `ifelse` can work? `df$column_name = ifelse(df$column_name > 5, 1, ifelse(df$column_name < 5, 0, df$column_name)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work:

```
data.frame(cbind(df[1],apply(df[-1],2,function(x) +(x > 5))))
    gene SampleA SampleB
1 Gene 1       1       1
2 Gene 2       0       1
3 Gene 3       1       0
```

Answer (score 0):

A tidyverse option.

```
library(dplyr)

mutate(df, across(-Gene, ~ + (. > 5)))

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   Gene   `Sample A` `Sample B`
#   <chr>       <int>      <int>
# 1 Gene 1          1          1
# 2 Gene 2          0          1
# 3 Gene 3          1          0
```

Data

```
df <- structure(list(Gene = c("Gene 1", "Gene 2", "Gene 3"), `Sample A` = c(10.23, 
2.89, 9.66), `Sample B` = c(11.2, 6.76, 4.34)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```